Inkscape overwrites extensions.xml at startup thus it does not take the python interpreter into account
I followed this guide to define a custom python interpreter (my system default python), so I edited /Users/amasson/Library/Application Support/org.inkscape.Inkscape/config/inkscape/preferences.xml with the foollowing:
...
<group
id="extensions"
python-interpreter="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3"
...

But when I start inkscape, the file gets overwritten and the python-interpreter="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3" part is removed.
Thus my extension (inkscape-silhouette) does not work.
What can I do to set the python interpreter?
